# Swagger Custom Tag Removal Python

Tags: python, json, swagger

I have a swagger json file. Sample :

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "tags": [
  {
    "name": "Tag1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Tag2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Tag3"
  },
  {
    "name": "Tag4"
  }
],
"paths": {
  "/api/v1/entities/{entityId}/status": {
    "post": {
      "tags": [
        "Tag1",
        "Tag3"
      ],
      .
      .
      .
    }
    "get": {
      "tags": [
        "Tag1",
        "Tag3"
      ],
      .
      .
      .
    }
  },
  "/api/v1/entities": {
    "post": {
      "tags": [
        "Tag2",
        "Tag3"
      ]
      .
      .
      .
    }
  }
}
```

I want to remove tags which are present in a list eg: ["Tag3", "Tag5"] from both the top-level tags list and all the individual paths as well, wherever present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple iteration and filtering:

```
updated_tags = [d for d in tags if d['name'].upper() not in (tag.upper() for tag in REMOVE_TAGS)]
dict['tags'] = updated_tags
paths = shell_json['paths']
for path, httpMethods in paths.items(): 
    for httpMethod, data in httpMethods.items():
        tags = data['tags']
        data['tags'] = [x for x in tags if x not in REMOVE_TAGS]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the JSON twice.
In the first time iterate and check which tags are kept as lists (store them in a list for example)
Then in the second iteration remove each tag that appears in the list you saved